# Weight painting an object

Tags: weight-painting

[image]

In the picture above I have two feet. The blue one is the one I have selected and gone into weight paint mode. I'm trying to change some vertices to red in weight paint mode but don't really understand how to do this. When I use the brush on the foot, nothing happens. It simply remains blue. It also doesn't show me vertices. It appears solid. If I enable wire frame mode, it shows all the vertices but doesn't allow for selecting certain vertices.

How can I paint specific vertices along the seam of my foot red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your screenshot the *weight* and *radius* of your brush are set to `0`, and you are using the *subtract* brush.

If you set them to higher values and pick a brush like *mix*, then it should work:

[image]

Comment: Also make sure you are using the correct brush.

Comment: Thank you. It works exactly as expected with the right brush. I had to put the radius to 9 and zoom in or it grabbed too many vertices. Thank you both! <3

Comment: @SteveHunt Good point, added