# Weight paint, I can subtract but can't add

Tags: animation, weight-painting

When I try to add weight paint it does not do anything, but when I subtract it works fine. How can I add weight paint for my rig?

Comment: Could you post a screen shot of your brush settings

Comment: Where are they? (im a little new to blender)?

Comment: Hit T on the keyboard.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14374/599

Answer (score 3):

Hit <kbd>T</kbd> to open up your brush settings. Chose the draw brush:

[image]

Set the Weight to 1, and the strength to 1. Also set the blend to Mix.

[image]

<sub>*Click Images to view larger versions*</sub>