# How to manipulate a smoke simulation to look like a realistic candle flame

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to figure out how to adjust my flame. It's a calm flame with *Noise Method-Strength* set to zero and all *Vorticity* settings all set to zero. My flame currently tapers flat like a cone and somewhat rounded and wavy at the tip. I'd like to have it go straight up for about two thirds and then taper into a point but not a flat taper. I'd like the taper to be a bit rounded. What settings do I need to play with to get this effect? The effect I'm looking for would be like a candle or lighter flame.

Also, I'd like to know what settings to play with to change the curve of color transitions in the flame? I'm currently only able to, either have the two colors blend flat and gradient or a hard transition in color where the top color curves like an arc downward to the next blend of color and I'd like to reverse that curvature upward like the effect is in a real candle flame. All arc curvatures in color transitions are upward in a real flame.

Comment: Why is this getting CVed?

Comment: Try experimenting with the density and temp diff for the domain object. Lower density and/or higher temp diff give faster rising smoke/flames, which results in a more pointed shape, while higher density and/or lower temp diff give slower rising smoke/flames, thus giving a rounder shape. However, this will also result in a shorter flame.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson please add a images (or a blend file)that show what you have. It's hard to understand what you are after just by description.

Comment: IMO this a perfectly reasonable question, it's specific and the OP as already attempted it before posting.

Comment: I tried your suggestions SithOfFour. I was able to smooth out some of the cone shape effect, which is great but I still can't seem to get the tip rounded to a point. Still struggling with blending my colors to get the effect I'm looking for though. Can't seem to get the transitions right as I described before.Here is the link to my blend file www.pasteall.org/blend/33531.

Comment: I've tried a few things on your .blend, but I can't get it quite right. One thing you may want to try though, is subdividing the plane you're using as the flow, and weight painting it with stronger weight in the centre and weaker weight by the edge, then under `Smoke Flow Advanced` select the vertex group. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14374/weight-painting-an-object

Comment: And, when you address someone, please put a @ in front of their name. That way they'll get a notification. Please also include the http:// part of URLs, to turn them into clickable links.

Comment: @SixthOfFour I tried your suggestions again with subdivision and weight painting. It didn't work. I will keep trying new things and doing some more research. I think you may be on the right track and that my mesh has something to do with why I'm not getting the shape I want. I'll post anything I find out. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the shape of the flames quite well by shaping the flow object. Here I've used a transparent cone as the flow object. I added some loop cuts to its sides to be able to make it slightly rounded, but I don't think this shape is exactly what you want. You will have to model the shape to fit your needs.

The flow object's material:
[image]

The domain material:
[image]

The flame texture:
[image]
The colour ramp is simply the default one from Quick Smoke, with just changed alpha levels.

The domain settings:
[image]

The flow object settings:
[image]

And the result:
[image]

If you use high transparency on the flames, the flow object may become visible although it's fully transparent. This is because you see where the flames are emitted from. To get around this, simply hide the flow object inside the lighter and make the lighter a collision object, to prevent the flames from seeping through its faces. Depending on whether you want to move the lighter around or not, you will need to change the Collision type. Animated = manual animation, Rigid = automatic animation by rigid body physics, Static = not moving.
[image]

[And an example .blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33545)

As I said, you will probably need to model the shape further, and also tweak the settings to your liking. This is simply meant to be a pointer in the right direction.

Furthermore, you have your flames rising far to fast, and they reach the upper boundary of the domain object before they come together into a singular point. If I were you, I'd delete the entire sim, keeping only the lighter object and start over with the flow and domain objects.

Comment: thanks man. I noticed the issue with the flame rising above the domain so that's a really good point. I'll start over. Problem solved.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson If SixthOfFour solved your issue, you can accept the answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers